# How to add two parameters from the url

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I display in my web page the result of `int1 + int2`? And can I know if it's an integer or a string? Here is my code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/add/:int1/:int2' do
  puts #{params[:int1]} + #{params[:int2]}
end
```

Comment: The params hash always contains `String`s, you need to convert them. Also, without quotes `"` after the puts, `#` will be interpretted as a comment, so at the moment you will just get a blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"#{params[:int1].to_i + params[:int2].to_i}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass it in url

```
http://yourdomain/add/2/3 #=> this will display 5  :int1 => 2, :int2 => 3
```

for embedding/interpolating variables use double quotes with puts

```
puts "#{params[:int1]} + #{params[:int2]}"
```

Comment: I did that, but my program doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/add/:int1/:int2' do
  sum = params[:int1].to_i + params[:int2].to_i
  "#{sum}"
end
```

I have changed the following:

- Removed `puts` - it's fine for debug, but Sinatra uses the return value, not STDOUT (which frameworks based around CGI might use) to output via web server. I am assuming here you are viewing in a browser.
- Removed the `#{ variable }` syntax - this is for inserting calculations into `String` results, and is not needed here. If you were building up a more complex string, it could be the way to go.
- Converted the params to `Fixnum`, using `to_i` they will always be `String` initially. Which conversion to apply, and how to validate you really have convertable numbers, well that's a bit more complicated, perhaps another question if it bothers you.
- Finally, returned number as a `String`, using string interpolation, because if you return just a number, Sinatra takes that for the HTTP status code.

Note that the separation into calculation, and turning the result into a string, is not strictly necessary. I have done it here just to show how the two parts are in fact different things you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's more readable with block parameters:

```
get "/add/:int1/:int2" do |a, b|
  "#{a.to_i + b.to_i}"
end
```

You can even use Regular Expressions to ensure integers:

```
get %r{/add/(\d+)/(\d+)} do |a, b|
  "#{a.to_i + b.to_i}"
end
```