# Ruby is_a?(Integer) issues

Tags: ruby

I am trying to test if my variables are Integer, here is the code :

```
if (params[:int1].is_a?(Integer) && params[:int2].is_a?(Integer))
  add(params[:int1], params[:int2])
else
  puts "Need two integers"
end
```

If you know why it doesn't works, you have all my attention.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: `is_a?` checks for the exact type and does not perform any coercion between string and integer types. My guess is your parameters are strings. Try checking if they're numeric using regular expressions or constructing the integers and catching argument errors.

Comment: params[] is either a string, or nil. `params[].is_a?(Integer)` will never be true.

Comment: Is this related to [How to add two parameters from the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656505/how-to-add-two-parameters-from-the-url)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params= { int1: "1" }

puts params[:int1].class

> String
```

Your params hash probably contains string values instead of Integers. If you want to check if a string is a valid integer, you can try validating it against a regex like so:

```
if /\d+/=~ params[:int1]
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: because if it really is an integer: `42.is_a?(Integer) #=> true`

Comment: I tried with your solution  (if /\d+/=~ params[:int1]) but i have now an Internal server error :/

Answer (score 0):

params[] stores only strings. You need to cast them to integers.

Try something like:

```rb
params[:int1].empty? ? raise EmptyIntegerException : my_int1 = params[:int1].to_i
```

Comment: (Assuming it's Rails we're talking about; hash values can be anything in general. I'd also use `present? ` to move the non- exceptional code closer to the test.)

Comment: You're right. But Probably I would go with something like `my_int1 = params[:int1].to_i if params[:int1].present?` instead the ternary.